# How can i check if there is a global or local variable

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

I want to check if that variable exists and print it if it does.

```
x = 10 

def example(): 

z = 5

print("X (Global variable) : ",x) 
print("Z (example() : ",z)

example() 

print(z)
```

When i add `print(z)` it will obviously raises an error because there is no variable called z.

Thanks for the answers guys. (specially Jasper, kevin and icantcode)

```
x = 10 
def example(): 

z = 5

example() 


try:
    print(z)
except NameError:
    print("There is no global variable called Z! ")
```

Comment: Is `z=5` supposed to be indented? If so, also `print("Z (example() : ",z)` will result in a `NameError`.

Comment: In what situation would you not know what variables you have defined?

Comment: in your case I'd think that just `print(locals())` or `print(globals())` would give you the information you want for understanding scopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most straight forward way would be to try to use it and if it fails do something else:

```
try:
    something_with(z)
except NameError:
    fallback_code()
```

you could also check dictionaries of `locals()` and `globals()`

```
if 'z' in locals() or 'z' in globals():
    print(z)
else:
    fallback_code()
```

Answer (score 7):

The built-in methods `locals()` and `globals()` return a dictionary of local/global variable names and their values.

```
if 'z' in locals():
    print(z)
```

Comment: @bonum77 no, it could be neither.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    print(z)
 except NameError:
    print("No variable named z!")
```

This code try's to print z and if there is no variable named z, it will run the code under except.

Comment: Don't use bare `except`.  You want something like `except NameError`.